# How to use two foreign keys as primary key on Hibernate entity annotation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I wanna make a primary key from 2 foreign keys using Hibernate entity annotation : 
    [image: look at the picture please]
**

- **How can i make  this two foreign keys "comID" and "reference" as
  Primary Key for LigneCommande table with Hibernate annotation !!
  Thank you :)**

I tried this code but it didnt work :

**Class "Produit" :**

```
public class Produit implements Serializable{

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "LigneCommande", catalog = "mkyongdb", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "reference", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "commande_id", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<Commande> commande;


    public List<Commande> getCommande() {
        return commande;
    }

    public void setCommande(List<Commande> commande) {
        this.commande = commande;
    }
}
```

**Class "Commande" :**

```
@Entity
public class Commande implements Serializable{

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "commande")
    private List<Produit> produit;

public List<Produit> getProduit() {
        return produit;
    }

    public void setProduit(List<Produit> produit) {
        this.produit = produit;
    }
}
```

**On top of that I have not any exception or error !!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution :

```
public class LigneCommande implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
    protected LigneCommandePK ligneCommandePK;

    @Column(name = "quantite")
    private int quantite;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @JoinColumn(name = "produit_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Produit produit;
    @JoinColumn(name = "commande_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Commande commande;
}
```

**This the Class "Produit" :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "produit")
public class Produit implements Serializable {@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "produit")
    private Collection<LigneCommande> ligneCommandeCollection;
}
```

And this is the association class :

```
@Embeddable
public class LigneCommandePK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "commande_id")
    private int commandeId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "produit_id")
    private int produitId;
}
```

And it works, look at the picture : 
[image]